# not generating report in windows rdlc report viewer 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, report-viewer2012

I have a system which uses Microsoft SDLC ReportViewer 2012, i watched a video on YT on how to integrate this on my system but as i do it my system can't create the report, as it was on the video it should create it in the path just like below
[image]

Comment: _can't create the report_  Could you explain what exactly this means?  What video are you talking about.  If that is a screenshot of the video, notice that it's using VS2010, so maybe find a more up to date tutorial as no doubt there have been changes (maybe subtle) in the process and usage

Comment: You should provide more information, such as what you did, what videos you referenced, etc.